# Getting UUID’s by providing only the crypto coins name/ticker

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, discord.js

I’m building a Discord bot using the Discord.JS module, and using NodeJS. I’m trying to add a simple crypto-price feature to my bot.

For now, I’m using the following code:

```js
const unirest = require("unirest");

const req = unirest("GET", "https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com/coin/Qwsogvtv82FCd/price");

req.query({
    "referenceCurrencyUuid": "yhjMzLPhuIDl"
});

req.headers({
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com",
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "X",
    "useQueryString": true
});

req.end(function (res) {
    if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);

    console.log(res.body);
});
```

So basically, you have to provide the UUID of the desired crypto coin to request information, but I want my users to be able to do (for example) `!price bitcoin` or `!price btc`, but this requires the command to be like `!price Qwsogvtv82FCd`.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [API documentation](https://rapidapi.com/Coinranking/api/coinranking1/), you can see that instead of using the coin price endpoint, you could use the search suggestion (`https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com/search-suggestions`), where you can search for a coin by its name or symbol. It returns an object like the one below. If you check the objects in `data.coins`, they have keys like `uuid`, `name`, `symbol`, and `price`:

```json
{
  "status":"success",
  "data":{
    "coins":[
      {
        "uuid":"Qwsogvtv82FCd",
        "iconUrl":"https://cdn.coinranking.com/gNsKAuE-W/bitcoin_btc.svg",
        "name":"Bitcoin",
        "symbol":"BTC",
        "price":"65955.43592725793773050345"
      },
      {...}
    ],
    "exchanges":[
      {...},
      {...}
    ],
    "markets":[...]
  }
}
```

Your current code doesn't really do anything and it doesn't even have discord.js code. Here is a sample code with some explanation:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
// I'm using node-fetch instead of unirest
// make sure you install it using npm i node-fetch
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const RAPID_API_KEY = 'YOUR RAPID API KEY';
const TOKEN = 'YOUR DISCORD API TOKEN';
const client = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
});
const prefix = '!';

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command !== 'price') return;
  if (!args[0]) return message.reply('Please provide a coin!');

  try {
    // get the search query
    let query = args[0].toLowerCase();
    // call the API
    let coins = await searchCoin(query);

    // if there is no search result, or something went wrong, exit w/ a message
    if (!coins || coins.length === 0)
      return message.reply(`No result for \`"${query}"\``);

    // check the first result only
    let coin = coins[0];
    // if there is an exact match, send the price returned from the API
    if (
      coin.name.toLowerCase() === query ||
      coin.symbol.toLowerCase() === query
    )
      return message.reply(
        `The current price of **${coin.name} (${coin.symbol})** is **${coin.price} USD**`,
      );

    // if there is no exact match, just send the coin name and symbol in a message
    message.reply(
      `No exact result found. Did you mean **${coin.name} (${coin.symbol})**?`,
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    message.reply('Oops, there was an error. Please try again later.');
  }
});

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot is connected...');
});

client.login(TOKEN);

async function searchCoin(query) {
  const url = `https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com/search-suggestions?query=${query}`;

  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com',
      'X-RapidAPI-Key': RAPID_API_KEY,
    },
  };
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, options);
    const json = await response.json();

    return json.status === 'success' ? json.data?.coins : null;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return null;
  }
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]